# How to correctly $parse elements in a loop?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to parse some strings of a loop indexed by $index and using them into datepickers , so i ended up using $parse and not $eval.

During debug i alway get this error

```
$parse is not a function
```

Here is the directive:

```
.directive('dispatcherDate', function (DISPATCHER_BROADCAST,$parse) {
            return {
              restrict: 'A',
              require: "ngModel",
              link : function(scope, elem, attrs,ngModelCtrl,$parse) {
                  var attributes = attrs;
                      scope.$on(DISPATCHER_BROADCAST.stuffLoaded,function(){
                            var parent = $(elem).parent();
                            var dtp = parent.datetimepicker({
                                format: "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss",
                                useCurrent: false,
                                showTodayButton: false,
                                defaultDate :$parse(attributes.ngModel),
                            });
                            dtp.on("dp.change", function (e) {
                                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(moment(e.date).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
                                scope.$apply();
                            });
                      });
              }
            };
          })
```

Where did i get wrong on how to use $parse?is it anyway correct the choiche of using $parse instead of $eval?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you get access to the value that `ngModel` points to using `ngModelCtrl.$viewValue`.

But if you want to use `$parse`, remove `$parse` from your link function parameters. You are creating a new variable for it, but it is not injected there. It gets injected above that, when declaring the directive:

```
.directive('dispatcherDate', function (DISPATCHER_BROADCAST,$parse) {
```

Also, parse against the scope:

```
defaultDate: $parse(attributes.ngModel)(scope)
```